# Are there partition recovery software available that support 4k sector drives?

Tags: hard-drive, advanced-format

I have several 2TB Western Digital EARS hard drives in my WHS 2011 server that suddenly became "not initialized".

I'm currently trying [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), but after one quick analyze I get the following message:

```
Disk /dev/sdc - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - CHS 243202 255 63
Check the harddisk size: HD jumpers settings, BIOS detection...
The harddisk (2000 GB / 1863 GiB) seems too small! (< 4000 GB / 3726 GiB)
```

I'm suspecting this might be due to the hard drive having 4k sectors.

Are there partition recovery software available that support 4k sector drives?

Comment: One workaround is to connect the drive to a motherboard and Windows OS that understands 4k sectors, then use a windows based recovery software like this one (this is the best imho)...http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm

Comment: I've always had good luck with [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva)

Comment: @Moab Thanks for the suggestion.  GetDataBack is working great!  I've already recovered data from one drive and the second drive is being recovered as I type this.  If you could, please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround is to connect the drive to a motherboard and Windows OS that understands 4k sectors, then use a windows based recovery [software like this one](http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm) (this is the best imho)

.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In TestDisk, instead of Analyse, select Geometry. Select Sector Size, and set it to 4096.

Comment: After I'm complete with the recovery with GetDataBack, I will try this suggestion.  Thanks for the response.